# Bug : SpagoBI 5.2 Meta can't add relationship from cube to dimensions while creating OLAP cube

Tags: open-source, reporting, spagobi

I'm using SpagoBI 5.2 Meta for creating Olap cube.I could create a database connection with Mysql database and imported physical tables.But It doesn't identify foreign key relationships in the physical tables. By right clicking on business classes, I have created dimensions and cube but when I try to edit business model to "Add relationship" ,the "finish" button on the GUI is disabled all the time.What may be the reasons for this.Do I need to add any inbound,outbound relationships first?
[Here I've attached screenshot of GUI that has disabled "finish" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjpVn.png)
Best Regards!!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set what is dimension and what is fact in your model.

You can do this by right click in the table (Olap > Create Cube or Create Dimension).

After do this for all tables in your model, you can add relationships with no problem.

[Detail of the submenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB95B.png)